# Firebase Sends Notification for removeValue Operation

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

So I have a functionality in my app wherein a user can post or delete any alert. If a new alert is posted other users must get a notification regarding it. Firebase push notification works good when a new data is added to the database but if a post has been deleted (`dataRef.child(root_child).removeValue();`) it still sends notification to the user which is not required. How to handle this situation?

**index.js**

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.sendNotificationAlert = functions.database.ref(`AlertPost/{pushId}`).onWrite(event => {
const getDeviceTokensPromise = admin.database().ref(`/Token/token_no`).once('value');
  const getBody=admin.database().ref(`/AlertPost`).once('value');
  var title_input='You have a new Alert';
  var contentAlert = event.data.val();
  var body_input=contentAlert.description;
  //const tokensSnapshot = results[0];

  return Promise.all([getDeviceTokensPromise,getBody]).then(results => {
  const tokensSnapshot = results[0];
  const notify=results[1];

  if (!tokensSnapshot.hasChildren()) {
    return console.log('There are no notification tokens to send to.');
  }
  console.log('There are', tokensSnapshot.numChildren(), 'tokens to send notifications to.');
  var contentAlert = event.data.val();

  // Notification details.
  const payload = {
    data: {
      title: title_input,
      body: body_input
      //icon: follower.photoURL
    },
    notification: {
      title: title_input,
      body: body_input
    }

  };

  const tokens = Object.keys(tokensSnapshot.val());

  //token_send(admin,tokensSnapshot,tokens,payload,title_input);

  // Send notifications to all tokens.
  return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, payload).then(response => {
    console.log("Successfully sent message:", response);
    // For each message check if there was an error.
    const tokensToRemove = [];
    response.results.forEach((result, index) => {
      const error = result.error;

      if (error) {
        console.error('Failure sending notification to', tokens[index], error);
        // Cleanup the tokens who are not registered anymore.
        if (error.code === 'messaging/invalid-registration-token' ||
            error.code === 'messaging/registration-token-not-registered') {
          tokensToRemove.push(tokensSnapshot.ref.child(tokens[index]).remove());
        }
      }
    });

    return Promise.all(tokensToRemove);
  });

});


});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check if the previous value of the event DataSnapshot is already deleted. Check this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events#reading_the_previous_value) for more information.

```
exports.makeUppercase = functions.database.ref('/messages/{pushId}/original').onWrite((event) => {

  // Only edit data when it is first created.
  if (event.data.previous.exists()) {
    return;
  }

  // Exit when the data is deleted.
  if (!event.data.exists()) {
    return;
  }

});
```

You could also check this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49421930/firebase-sends-notification-for-removevalue-operation/49427054#49427054) for reference.